# Codeigniter Pagination Numbering

Tags: codeigniter

does codeigniter pagination have automatic numbering to show, following every page.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question?

Comment: btw, "pages" are actually a "offset", so 'page 2' link will be your perpage increment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does have automatic numbering:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html